# AttrChanged not fired with two-way binding

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement two-way binding with custom layout. Just to understand how it works I created:

FirstViewModel.java

```
public class FirstViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private int intValue;

    public void init() {/*if (intValue == null) intValue = new ObservableInt(0);*/}

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }
}
```

Then CustomLaayout.java

```
public class CustomLaayout extends LinearLayoutCompat {

    private int intValue;

    public CustomLaayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLaayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomLaayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("intValue")
    public static void setIntValue(CustomLaayout customLaayout, int value) {
        if (customLaayout.getIntValue() != value)
            customLaayout.setIntValue(value);
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "intValue", event = "intValueAttrChanged")
    public static int getIntValue(CustomLaayout customLaayout) {
        return customLaayout.getIntValue();
    }

    @BindingAdapter("intValueAttrChanged")
    public static void setIntValueListener(CustomLaayout customLaayout, final InverseBindingListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setIntValue(this, getIntValue() + 1);
        //CustomLaayout.setIntValue(this, getIntValue() + 1);
    }
}
```

And fragment_first.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="view_model"
            type="com.example.bindings2.FirstViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.example.bindings2.CustomLaayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:intValue="@={view_model.intValue}">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layout_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(view_model.intValue)}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/model_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(view_model.intValue)}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:onClickListener="@{customLayout}" />

    </com.example.bindings2.CustomLaayout>
</layout>
```

Now, starting the app it works correctly, but clicking the button (so changing the `CustomLaayout` intValue) nothing happens, and the `setIntValueListener` method isn't called. I'm certainly missing something, perhaps an `OnChangeListener` that fires the change event...
I searched the web but nothing helped me.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

regards,
Livio.

PS: of course I could set an `ObservableInt` as intValue in `FirstViewModel` and pass a reference to `CustomLayout` (e.g. `app:intValue="@{view_model.getIntValue()}"`) and it should work, but I need to understand the process in order to implement other more complex layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved. `FirstViewModel` must implement `Observable`

```
public class FirstViewModel extends ViewModel implements Observable {

    private transient PropertyChangeRegistry mCallbacks;

    // other stuff...

 @Override
    public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        if (mCallbacks == null) {
            mCallbacks = new PropertyChangeRegistry();
        }
        mCallbacks.add(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.remove(callback);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void notifyChange() {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
        }
    }

    public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null);
        }
    }
```

and in `setIntValue(int intValue)` method add `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.intValue);`

Also `CustomLayout` must implement `Observable` (same as for `FirstViewModel`, adding `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.intValue);` in `setIntvalue`).

Finally `setIntValueListener` becomes

```
@BindingAdapter("intValueAttrChanged")
    public static void setIntValueListener(CustomLaayout customLaayout, final InverseBindingListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            customLaayout.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                    listener.onChange();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And it works...